# SAS ODS PDF Font MS MINCHO Unsearchable PDF File

Tags: pdf, search, fonts, sas, ods

When I create a PDF file using MS Mincho as fonts , the PDF file is not searchable. I did check MS MINCHO font is installed correctly in SAS and Windows. Can you please guide what I am missing. ?

```
        proc template;
           define style styles.smaller;
           parent = styles.printer;
              class fonts from fonts / 
                    'TitleFont2' = ("MS Mincho",10pt,Bold Italic)
                    'TitleFont' = ("MS Mincho",11pt,Bold Italic)
                    'StrongFont' = ("MS Mincho",8pt,Bold)
                    'EmphasisFont' = ("MS Mincho",8pt,Italic)
                    'FixedEmphasisFont' = ("MS Mincho",7pt,Italic)
                    'FixedStrongFont' = ("MS Mincho",7pt,Bold)
                    'FixedHeadingFont' = ("MS Mincho",7pt,Bold)
                    'BatchFixedFont' = ("MS Mincho",5pt)
                    'FixedFont' = ("MS Mincho",7pt)
                    'headingEmphasisFont' = ("MS Mincho",9pt,Bold Italic)
                    'headingFont' = ("MS Mincho",9pt,Bold)
                    'docFont' = ("MS Mincho",8pt);
              class Table from Output /
                    rules = ALL
                    cellpadding = 2pt     /* Reduced from 4pt to 2pt */
                    cellspacing = 0.25pt
                    borderwidth = 0.75pt;
           end;
        run;
        
        ods pdf file="test.pdf" style=styles.smaller;
        
        proc print data=sashelp.class;
        run;
        
        ods pdf close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in the system with SAS Registry
SAS KB Note:
https://support.sas.com/kb/46/128.html